# How to add a new row in pandas based on a condition from the first column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I have the following pandas dataframe:Example [input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiOfR.png)

I would like to iterate through the rows in only the first column and if it meets a condition (ie contains the string 'hello') I would like to add an empty row above this with only the first column being populated.

Example [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zd8WX.png)

I have tried:
`df.loc[0] ='My new title'`

This adds a row but the title is on every column.

I'm guessing the syntax would be something like:
`

```
for i in df.iloc[0]:
    if i == 'hello':
    df.loc[-1] ='My new title'
print(df)
```

`
This is not working either - could someone point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean I have a dataframe with no "titles"? A dataframe always has titles, it can have the wrong ones yes, only `Pandas Series` can have no title. Is it possible to add some example data?

Comment: @Erfan I have edited this part out (the columns are just Unamed: 0 etc) I also added input/output images. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new row in this way

```
import pandas

data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]] 
df = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age']) 

df2 = pandas.DataFrame([['My new title', None]], columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
rownumber = 0
for i in df.iloc[0:,0]:

    if i == "nick":
        df = pandas.concat([df.iloc[:rownumber], df2, df.iloc[rownumber:]]).reset_index(drop=True)
        rownumber += 1

    rownumber += 1
```

this will add a new row before every "nick"

Comment: Thank you for this - I did this however, is there any way I can append `df2` (the title) on the row above 'nick' is found? I have tried `df.loc[-1] ` this doesn't work. Also the row position will constantly change as there might be many instances of the name 'nick' - do you know how I could approach this? thanks

Comment: thank you - this what I was after. Currently doesnt work for my code as I only put in `df2 = pd.DataFrame({"My title here"})`. It seems to remove most of the columns except for the last 2! I reckon I need to put column names - is there a way to add empty col names?

Comment: df.columns give you all the columns of the dataframe df, like this
df2 = pandas.DataFrame([['My new title', None]], columns = df.columns)

Comment: very strange if I do that - i keep getting the error message `9 columns passed, passed data had 2 columns`